# Poner Menu Select al lado izquierdo en el footer de un Modal

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, modal

```
<div class="modal-footer">
    <form class="form-inline" action="#" method="post">
        <div class="form-group"> 
            <label class="text-muted" for="doc_type">Format:</label>                                            
                <select class="custom-select border-0 field pl-0" id="doc_type" name="selectFormat">
                    <option value="1">MP4</option>
                    <option value="2">MP3</option>
                </select> 
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-light border-0 text-dark">Download</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light border-0 text-dark" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que busco es poner el Label y el Select al lado izquierdo. No soy experto en bootstrap, estuve probando con mr-auto pero sin resultados. Quizas es algo simple, lo cual seria logico ya que no conozco del tema.

**EDIT:**

La otra solucion que puedo pensar es quitar la clase modal-footer, agregar mr-auto al button download y replicar el estilo del footer en css.

Aunque creo que seria hacer de mas.??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma de solucionar es con [Flex - auto margins](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/utilities/flex/#auto-margins)

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="modal d-block" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
      </div>
      
      <!-- MODAL-FOOTER -->
      <div class="modal-footer d-block">
        <form action="#" method="post">
          <div class="d-flex mb-3">
            <div class="mr-auto p-2 d-inline-flex align-items-baseline">
              <label class="text-muted px-2" for="doc_type">Format:</label>               
                <select class="form-control pl-0" id="doc_type" name="selectFormat">
                    <option value="1">MP4</option>
                    <option value="2">MP3</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="p-2">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary border-0">Download</button>
            </div>
            <div class="p-2">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-light border-0 text-dark" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--// MODAL-FOOTER -->
    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Info-Soporte:

> > Unfortunately, IE10 and IE11 do not properly support auto margins on flex items whose parent has a non-default justify-content value.
>
> ---
>
> (Google-Translater):
>   Desafortunadamente, IE10 e IE11 no soporta correctamente los márgenes
>   automáticos en los elementos flexibles cuyo padre tiene un valor de
>   contenido de justificación no predeterminado. Vea esta respuesta de
>   [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37535548) para más detalles.